# How to decompose GetElementPtr instruction in LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

for a GetElementPtr instruction in llvm, I would like to know how to calculate the result of it.

For example, an gep instruction and n indices and the result should be `val = base + index_1 * length_1 + index_2 * length_2 + ... + index_10 * length_10`

While index is integer type value saying that how many element away from the base and length is the length of one element.

My question is I do not know how to retrieve these information from `llvm::GetElementPtrInst`, I've searched the internet and there are multiple sayings and no clear illustration.

Please help, thanks!